# How to enable cloud init on first boot when deploying VMs on OpenStack using .raw

Tags: linux, openstack, cloud-init

So I am converting custom built .iso to .raw. Deployed a VM on OpenStack using this .raw but I am unable to ssh into this machine.

I used GUI console and was able to login to this OpenStack VM using username and password. Once I am logged in, I restarted the cloud-init service and that resolved the ssh issue. I can ssh into the machine just fine.
Now the question is how do I make sure that enabling and restarting the cloud-init service are as part of first boot when deploying VMs on OpenStack.

I know I can pass the script when using UI to deploy VMs on OpenStack website but the requirement is this should be as part of the image itself. That means, I should just deploy a vm using .raw and the enabling and starting of cloud-init service should be part of the .raw image itself.

I am new to Linux or IT in general. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Maybe the keypoint is that **[cloud-init](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit)** system which is an open-source package from Ubuntu that is available on various Linux distributions was installed or configured wrong. You should be sure that the cloud-init system which running in **.iso** image was working before convert to **.raw** format.

> how do I make sure that enabling and restarting...

If you want to find it out, you could create instance with `--user-data` [parameter](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/rocky/user/user-data.html).